# How to get files from resources folder after exporting as Jar file

Tags: java, maven

public class GetFiles {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
    String myDocument = System.getProperty("user.home")+"/Documents/";
    String fileName = "Sample.txt";
    
    InputStream in = GetFiles.class.getResourceAsStream("/"+fileName);
    
    File outputFile = new File(myDocument+fileName);
    
    Files.copy(in, outputFile.toPath());
    

}
```

}

// This code is not working after exporting as Jar file

Comment: It goes in /src/main/resources You should also show your code in case you're accessing it wrongly

Comment: Code something like `String target = "C:/User/Documents/copied.xlsx";try (InputStream in = Copier.class.getResourceAsStream("/x.xlsx")) { Files.copy(in, Path.of(target)); }`